# aligning inputed text when it is outputted?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm working on a program that when the user enters text, they can specify how to align the output. So the user would enter there text then they would be asked what alignment and width they would want for the text (center, left, right, then the width). How would you get the code for the width and alignment? So far I only have the code that gets the users input, but I'm not sure how to get the program to have the user enter their criteria (left,right,center and width)and then align the input given by the user. Here is what I've got so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<string> text;
    string line;

    cout << "Enter Your Text:(to start a newline click enter. When done click enter 2 times " << endl;

    while (getline(cin, line) && !line.empty())
        text.push_back(line);

    cout << "You entered: " << endl;

    for (auto &s : text)
        cout << s << endl;
    cout << "Enter Left,Center,Right and Width: ";
    return 0;
}
```

I thought maybe I have to use `<iomanip>`? But I feel like there is another way. Input would be something like.

```
Hello My Name is Willi
John Doe
and I live in 
Kansas.
```

And then when the user enters the alignments, the text would align so say the user enters right alignment, width 10. The output should be the should be aligned to the right (like in a word processor) and it should have a width of 10 spaces (which I'm assuming would be whitespaces).

Comment: can you write an example of your input commands as you write them on your terminal and the expected output?

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis I edited what the input would be, and how the expected output should be like.

Comment: When the user enters Left and width=10, or Center and width=10 or Right and width=10 what is the expected output for your input example?

Comment: You would have to have a terminal that supports moving the cursor around. And for that, `iomanip` is not enough. You need the `ncurses` or `conio.h`(or whatever they use on windows). For starters, you can refresh current line by using `'\r` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line. And for most applications that may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach. It simply fills each line with whitespaces based on the alignment. Left alignment is basically the input text. You should probably also check if the alignment width is `>=` than the longest line of the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {

std::vector<std::string> text;
std::vector<std::string> output;
std::string line;
std::string align;
int width;

std::cout << "Enter Your Text (to start a newline click enter. When done click enter 2 times): \n";

while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty() )
    text.push_back(line);

std::cout << "You entered:\n\n";

for ( auto &s : text )
    std::cout << s << "\n";

std::cout << "Enter Left,Center,Right and Width: ";
std::cin >> align;
std::cin >> width;

for ( auto &s : text ) {

    int diff = width - s.size(),
        half = diff / 2;

    if ( align == "Right" ) {
        output.push_back( std::string(diff, ' ') + s );
    } else if ( align == "Center" ) {
        output.push_back( std::string(half, ' ') + s + std::string(diff - half, ' ') );
    } else {
        output.push_back( s );
    }

}

std::cout << "Aligned Output: \n\n";

for ( auto &s : output )
    std::cout << s << "\n";

return 0;

}
```

Test Cases (actual output has whitespaces, not `*`):

> Input ( alignment=Right, width=10 ):
>
> ```
> Hello my
> name is
> John Doe
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> **Hello my
> ***name is
> **John Doe
> ```
>
> Input ( alignment=Center, width=16 ):
>
> ```
> Hello my name
> is
> John Doe
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> *Hello my name**
> *******is*******
> ****John Doe****
> ```